# import OSM to GRASS not a valid flag error

Tags: openstreetmap, grass-gis, vector

I've downloaded an OpenStreetMap data extract from geofabrik.de. I installed the v.in.osm extension. When I run

```
v.in.osm -l input=country-latest.osm.pbf
```

it works well enough to identify the available OGR layers. However, when I try

```
v.in.osm input=country-latest.osm.pbf output=countrypoly type=boundary table=multipolygons
```

I get the following:

> ERROR: v.in.ogr: Sorry, `<T>` is not a valid flag
>   ERROR: v.in.ogr: Sorry, `<u>` is not a valid flag
>   ERROR: v.in.ogr failed
>   WARNING: No data base element files found

I've tried different layers within the .pbf, and different .pbf files, but I always get the same errors. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong? I'm using GRASS 7.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I just tried with "andorra-latest.osm.pbf" from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html but I failed to import data as well. One doubt: be sure that you have the latest v.in.osm addon installed - you can easily update all existing addons with 'g.extension.all -f'

Comment: I updated my addons, but the errors persist. Thank you for looking into this, Markus. It's good to know I'm not the only one having a problem!

Comment: I have posted the question here: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/2017-August/085941.html